# How rude is it to ask someone if they are a nerd or not?

Tags: offensive-language, cultural-correctness

I asked one of my new friends(a week), "On a scale of 1-10 how nerdy are you? Where do you fall?" She is from Chile and she said the question was very rude there. But I don't understand why. I only meant to ask whether she was a studious person or a more socializing person.

Comment: In the US (coming from a nerd), I see no problem with that comment. I do not know how other cultures perceive nerdiness, though.

Comment: I don't see why it would be rude, nor why studious as opposed to socializing is enough to define a nerd.

Comment: I see your point about defining a nerd but I just want to know how it was rude.

Comment: @Hank: I don't know if it's because I'm from a different culture (UK as opposed to US) - but to me, ***nerdy*** implies *characterized by an obsessive interest in something, especially technology*. I'm aware of the alternative sense *unfashionable and socially inept or boringly studious,* but it's my impression that's primarily used by *schoolchildren* (in the way we used to use ***swot*** when I was that age).

Comment: @FumbleFingers So are you saying "nerd" does or doesn't have a negative connotation **to you**?

Comment: @Hank: I said nothing about whether it has a negative connotation - but since you ask, I think I'd have to say that I'm sure the vast majority of native speakers would say the word itself is effectively "pejorative", even if they actually approve of people being very interested in things like technology.

Comment: This could be put on Interpersonal Relations Stack Exchange, and I have flagged this for being blatantly off-topic.

Comment: @Black and White I don't agree with that.  Whether words have positive or negative connotations is often addressed here. "Nerd" and "geek" over time and in different English-speaking countries would be useful to compare.

Comment: See also the "pejorative-language" tag.  That is, indeed, different from offensive, although some words can manage to be both.

Comment: Whether it's offensive or not is entirely up to the hearer.

Comment: There is always the connotation of "nerds are disadvantaged in the mating market", and that can rub people the wrong way easily.

Answer (score 0):

Being a 'nerd' implies that someone is more interested in things than in people. And that is deemed, by some, as being an unsociable thing. Therefore it becomes something not to be invited, to be thought of as one of those persons.

Thus it becomes rude to say that someone is a 'nerd'